# General rules for converting GRUB entries to GRUB 2?

Tags: grub2, live-cd

I would like to change an entry for a solution to boot from CD from legacy GRUB (looks like `title bla bla bla`) to an entry to a format compatible to GRUB 2 (the one that looks like `menuentry "bla bla bla" {`.

The original legacy GRUB entry is as follows:

```
title Boot From CD/DVD Drive
    kernel /boot/grub/memdisk.din
    initrd /boot/grub/sbootmgr.dsk
```

Is there any sort of conversion rule to change this to something like the example I've put here on the next line? (This is from my precise's grub.cfg.)

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-25-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos8)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root efc87ac0-daac-4a32-9a85-ea57beff0e28
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-25-generic root=UUID=efc87ac0-daac-4a32-9a85-ea57beff0e28 ro   quiet splash acpi_osi= $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-25-generic
}
```

Comment: (Better too much information than too little!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General rules for GRUB to GRUB2 conversion:

First, the root hard drive partition needs to be specified along with the partition type:

`insmod ext2`

`set root='(hd0,msdos8)'`

Then, the kernel is specified.  In GRUB, this was `kernel`.  In GRUB2, it's `linux`:

`linux   /boot/grub/memdisk.bin` (additional options can go here, such as a "set root" option for modern linux)

Then, the initial ramdisk is specified, which looks exactly the same as in legacy GRUB:

`initrd  /boot/grub/sbootmgr.dsk`